# Setting the correct connection pool size for Sidekiq on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, heroku, unicorn

The [sidekiq docs say you should increase your AR pool size](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#concurrency) to around 25 connections.

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: foo_production
  pool: 25
```

If you are using Heroku, [you can't use `application.yml`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#multi-process-servers). Instead, you need to use the `unicorn.rb` config file (if you are using unicorn):

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]

    config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
    config['pool']              = ENV['DB_POOL']      || 25

    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

But each Dyno runs 3 processes. I have one web Dyno and a worker Dyno. Does that mean the max pool size will be 150? 2 * 3 * 25?

Later, the guide says [we should include an initializer file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#bad-connections). But it's almost identical to the code in the `unicorn.rb` file. Do we need this in addition to the unicorn file?

```
config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
config['pool']              = ENV['DB_POOL'] || 5
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar questions and problems finding definitive answers!

Like many other computing problems I think there is not a definitive answer, each case is different and dependant on many factors such as Heroku configuration, Rails config, profile of application, Rails web server used, etc.

The best option may be to spin up a production like clone or [fork the Heroku app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app) and try different configurations with consistent loads, collecting data and then making an informed decision.

I believe for example if you have 3x Unicorn processes then you may need 3x DB_POOL - although ActiveRecord will lazily initiate these connections as and when needed.

I have used configuration in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` to fetch the database url to configure Sidekiq, something like;

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|

  # ...

  database_url = ENV['DATABASE_URL']
  if database_url
    pool_size = Sidekiq.options[:concurrency] # one example of what this could be...
    ENV['DATABASE_URL'] = "#{database_url}?pool=#{pool_size}" # only affects this process
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq database pool size and Web database pool size should not be the same or may not be the same.

```
require 'sidekiq'

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  ActiveRecord::Base.configurations['production']['pool'] = ENV["SIDEKIQ_DB_POOL_SIZE"] || 8
end
```

If we had set the Sidekiq concurrency as 8 , Database pool size must also be set to 8. So that The database can serve the 8 threads coming from Sidekiq concurrently.

This is different from Web server. Suppose we are using Puma server with 1 worker running with 10 threads, the database have to serve 10 threads coming from the Puma server according to that pool configuration in database.yml.

So to recap, in our example, DB pool will be 8 when serving Sidekiq and will be 10 when serving the application server(Puma in this case).

Comment: I think that just by changing that ActiveRecord::Base.configurations Hash in place you are not actually applying that change. You're probably missing something like `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:production)` afterwards, or, even better, `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(ActiveRecord::Base.connection_config.dup.tap{ |config| config[:pool] = })`

Comment: Actually, for an even more complete setup (that disconnects the previous pool leaving no ghost connections), check out the setup in https://stackoverflow.com/q/64880202/1290457